# C# winform removing and then adding more items to a panel control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using C# Winforms, I have a panel that is to display some custom controls.  I can add instances of the controls to the panel and if there are too many, the panel will scroll them.

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

The issue comes after I start removing items from the panel.  I am using:

```
myPanel.Controls.Remove(myControl);
myControl.Dispose();
```

however when I then go to add more controls to the panel, the new ones added will not display at all.

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(newControl);
```

newControl or any subsequent controls will not be visible.

Can anyone assist with this please, thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show the way you are creating those newControl(s) ? your removal seems to be ok, try to remove the call to Dispose, but really should be fine also having it so I suspect the new controls you create are somehow not properly added or created...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not clearing your panels. Try this:

```
mypanel.Controls.clear();
```

Comment: Yeah you have to clear the panel first of all to add some more other controls or user controls. Then only it will show the respective controls correctly